# How to handle sorting of complex objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns, sorting

How would one sort a list of objects that have more than one sortable element?

Suppose you have a simple object `Car` and car is a defined as such:

```
class Car {
    public String make;
    public String model;
    public int year;
    public String color;
    // ... No methods, just a structure / container
}
```

I designed a simple framework that would allow for multiple `SortOption`s to be provided to a `Sorter` that would then sort the list.

```
interface ISorter<T> {
    List<T> sort(List<T> items);
    void addSortOption(ISortOption<T> option);
    ISortOption<T>[] getSortOptions();
    void setSortOption(ISortOption<T> option);
}

interface ISortOption<T> {
    String getLabel();
    int compare(T t1, T t2);
}
```

Example use

```
class SimpleStringSorter extends MergeSorter<String> {
    {
        addSorter(new AlphaSorter());
    }

    private static final class AlphaSorter implements ISortOption<String> {
        // ... implementation of alpha compare and get label
    }
}
```

The issue with this solution is that it is not easily expandable. If car was to ever receive a new field, say, currentOwner. I would need to add the field, then track down the sorter class file, implement a new sort option class then recompile the application for redistribution.

Is there an easier more expandable/practical way to sort data like this?

Comment: Look up the Comparator pattern or Comparer pattern.  You simply just want to abstract the less than, equal or greater than comparison while leaving the rest of the algorithm intact.

Comment: Peter - you should move this to be an answer :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you can use a comparator which has a method compare(a,b) which you can implement.

Then you can pass it in for the compare step (this is supported in nearly all standard libraries of most languages).

For example in java you can call

```
Collections.sort(fooList, new Comparator<Car>(){
    public int compare(Car a,Car b){
        return a.getModel().compareTo(b.getModel());
        // or compare what you want return -1, 0 or 1 
        // for less than, equal and greater than resp.
    }
});
```

To sort your lists according to a custom comparator

In java 8 there is a lambda syntax to create the Comparator in a single line.

This means there will be only one sorting algorithm to maintain and a bunch of comparators which can remain in the same class as what it is comparing, (or near the place where the comparing is taking place).

This also allows for a "tiered" sort, you can implement something like:

```
public static Comparator<T> createTieredComparator(final Comparator<? super T> comp1, final Comparator<? super T> comp2){
    return new Comparator<T>(){
        public int compare(T a,T b){
            int res = comp1.compare(a,b);
            if(res!=0)
                return res;
            else
                return comp2.compare(a,b);
        }
    };
}
```

This will prefer the comparison made by `comp1` and only return the result of `comp2` when they would be considered equal according to `comp1`.

Comment: I looks to be the better solution: hard to do less than add the field on the considered class and express "somewhere" how to deal with all the fields used in the comparison.

Answer (score 4):

Implement java.lang.Comparable and use collections like java.util.TreeSet that rely on "natural ordering."  Implementing the compareTo() method in the Comparable interface is a lot like [implementing an equals() method](http://glenpeterson.blogspot.com/search?q=compareTo) - that link contains an example of both.  **It is critical to implement equals() and hashcode() if you implement compareTo() and all three must be compatible with each other!**

```
private int compareNullHelper(Object a, Object b) {
    // sorts nulls first
    if (a == null) {
        if (b != null) { return -1; }
    } else if (b == null) { return 1; }
    return a.compareTo(b);
}

/** Sorts by make, model, year, color. */
@Override
public int compareTo(Car that) {
    // ensures consistency with equals()
    if (this.equals(that)) { return 0; }

    int ret = compareNullHelper(this.make, that.make);
    if (ret != 0) { return ret; }

    ret = compareNullHelper(this.model, that.model);
    if (ret != 0) { return ret; }

    ret = this.year - that.year;
    if (ret != 0) { return ret; }

    ret = compareNullHelper(this.color, that.color);
    if (ret != 0) { return ret; }

    // If you can't tell, return -1 which means that they are in the right
    // order but unequal - ensures consistency with equals()
    return -1;
}
```

Now you can write:

```
Set<Car> orderedCars = new TreeSet<Car>();
orderedCars.addAll(myCars);
```

If you need to sort according to different criteria, make additional Comparator classes (that's another Java API interface) for each sort order.  If you make Car implement Comparable and the compareTo() method of your Car class goes by make, model, year, color, you might want to make a `ByColorComparator implements Comparator` that compares by color, year, make, model.  Then say:

```
Set<Car> carsByColor = new TreeSet<Car>(new ByColorComparator());
orderedCars.addAll(myCars);
```

The built-in sorting in Java collections is insanely fast.  For years Java collections have been one of the best things about the platform.

One thing to note is that this technique will work with Hibernate or JPA (if you have an open database session) to automatically grab related objects from the database that may be needed for sorting.

Comment: I prefer the comparator variant: a car has no natural order and you should provide a comparator as *one* of the sorting strategies. Also, why play with Treeset if you only want to sort your collection?

Comment: @GlenPeterson, getting compilation problem in `return a.compareTo(b);` of `compareNullHelper` method. Would you mind clarifying it?